# Remote repo on Google Cloud VM - unable to connect and git push

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I'm trying to git push my project from my local computer to my Google Cloud VM. I set up a git repo on my local cpu as well as in my VM. When I do the following:
`git remote add live 'you@your-server:/path/to/bare_project.git / git push --set-upstream live master`

I receive this error:

```
git : ssh: Could not resolve hostname johnbot: Name or service not known
At line:2 char:1
+ git push --set-upstream live master
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ssh: Could not ...rvice not known:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Perhaps I'm simply not inputting my server correctly. What exactly is my Google Cloud VM's address? Is is `account@name-of-instance:/path/to/project'`, `'account@external-ip:...'` I see some examples that say your host name contains the location of your VM. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot push from your local git repo to your VM because it is not running a git server.

Instead, push to a public/private repository (GitHub, GitLab, Google Cloud Source Repositories) and then clone/pull the repository from the command line at the VM.

Comment: What constitutes as a git repo. I was able to install git onto my VM and create a repo via git init

Comment: @bighelpdiscord - git is a client command which creates a local repository. You cannot push a local repository to another system's local repository. To push to another system, you need to be running a git server on that system. There are other methods such as webhooks, but the git client does not initiate webhooks. Sort of like the difference between Google Chrome (git) and a web server (git server).

Comment: Would the solution be to push to say GitHub and then PULL via my VM?

Comment: @bighelpdiscord Yes, that is what my answer says.

Comment: My apologies. I will look into git pull. Thank you for your help